# Extracting the text from a Log using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, text, pattern-matching

I have a log message like this

> (12/12/2013 03:12:21 PM) 06:21:22.234 - 5463723 : ##Some Message##

i need to write a regular expression to extract **Some Message**  from above log record. How can i write a regular expression to extract the required words out. 
Note: I am using python language to parse the log files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(?<=##)[^#]*(?=##)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regex for that:

```
line.split("##", 2)[1]
```

This will split the line on the `##` character combination, and then return the second element. The first element is everything before the first `##`, and the second will then be the text between them.

Comment: i have written python code for this already.. But it's not efficient as regular expressions.